# Trouble with Image Maps, Safari, and Gmail for HTML email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have a quirky problem -- I'm sending an html email that contains some image mapped links.

My problem surrounds Gmail and Safari.

Strangely, emails when view from Gmail (and their image maps) function fine in Firefox, IE, and Chrome.  But, for some reason -- none of these same image mappws links work when viewed with Safari.

I'd first like to know why -- and then secondly, what's the best approach to overcome the problem.

Thank,

-R