# Dreamweaver Hotspot Links on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, dreamweaver, html-email

I'm setting up an html email with one jpeg and three different "hotspot" links to various items on the server. The email and links work perfectly on any desktop computer and android smartphone. On the iPhone, however, the hotspot links don't work. Is this an iPhone issue? Is there a fix without having to dive into a more heavily coded emailer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems based on [this article](http://blog.goolara.com/2014/06/05/image-maps-revisited/) that image maps are supported on iPhones only if they are contained in a table, otherwise the image will be resized but the links won't move around to match. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604222/image-map-not-working-on-ios-devices-with-large-images-that-get-rescaled-by-the)